# Oracle Query to Find Records If Count >= 2 and unique in column

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count, having

```
+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
| MEMRECNO | RECSTAT | IDSRCRECNO | IDNUMBER  |
+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
|   556787 | D       |          5 | 956645789 |
|   123456 | A       |          5 | 956645789 |
|   546578 | A       |          5 | 462454322 |
|   262441 | A       |          4 | 462454322 |
|   657855 | D       |          3 | 462454322 |
|   746877 | A       |          5 | 654988844 |
|   989455 | A       |          2 | 654988844 |
|   444863 | A       |          1 | 654988844 |
+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

I am attempting to write a query to select records where two or more sources (IDSRCRECNO) have same IDNUMBER. I have started the query with something along the lines of:

WHERE idnumber IN (SELECT idnumber from table GROUP by idnumber HAVING count(idnumber) >= 2

```
Expected Results:
```

MEMRECNO 546578 and 262441 included in results. This is because both records are active, the IDNUMBER's are identical and the IDSRCRECNO is different.

MEMRECNO 556787 and 123456 would not be included because even though the IDNUMBERS match, one of the records/recstat is Deleted (D).

Memrecno 262441 and 657855 would not be included because even though the IDNUMBERS match and IDSRCRECNO is different, one of the records/recstat is Deleted (D).

Memrecno 262441 and 657855 would not be included because even though the IDNUMBERS match and IDSRCRECNO is different, one of the records/recstat is Deleted (D).

Memrecno 746877, 989455, 444863 would be included because all three records are active, IDSRCRECNO is different and IDNUMBERs match.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So your second requirement is to **exclude** deleted (`recstat = 'D'`) records?

Comment: That is correct, recstat ='D' should not be included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what are you looking for?

I just added a `WHERE` clause to your inner query:

```
SELECT idnumber 
WHERE recstat <> 'D' 
FROM table GROUP by idnumber 
HAVING count(idnumber) >= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this like:

```
with data as (
    select 556787 memrecno, 'D' recstat, 5 idsrcrecno, 956645789 idnumber from dual union all
    select 123456 memrecno, 'A' recstat, 5 idsrcrecno, 956645789 idnumber from dual union all
    select 546578 memrecno, 'A' recstat, 5 idsrcrecno, 462454322 idnumber from dual union all
    select 262441 memrecno, 'A' recstat, 4 idsrcrecno, 462454322 idnumber from dual union all
    select 657855 memrecno, 'D' recstat, 3 idsrcrecno, 462454322 idnumber from dual union all
    select 746877 memrecno, 'A' recstat, 5 idsrcrecno, 654988844 idnumber from dual union all
    select 989455 memrecno, 'A' recstat, 2 idsrcrecno, 654988844 idnumber from dual union all
    select 444863 memrecno, 'A' recstat, 1 idsrcrecno, 654988844 idnumber from dual
)
select *
from (
    select memrecno, recstat, idsrcrecno, idnumber, count(distinct idsrcrecno) over (partition by idnumber) rec_cnt
    from data
    where recstat = 'A'
)
where rec_cnt > 1;
```

Which returns:

```
  MEMRECNO RECSTAT IDSRCRECNO   IDNUMBER    REC_CNT
---------- ------- ---------- ---------- ----------
    262441 A                4  462454322          2
    546578 A                5  462454322          2
    444863 A                1  654988844          3
    989455 A                2  654988844          3
    746877 A                5  654988844          3
```

This assumes you only want to see Active records.  The query would have to be changed if for example MEMRECNO = 444863 was not Active, but you still wanted it to show up (since there would still be 2 records with the same IDNUMBER and different IDSRCRECNO).  Just comment if that is what you are looking for and I will update this accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Craig. I tried running your query, but I'm getting unexpected results. It is showing for example 4 IDNUMBERS, but different REC_CNT)                                                      1234567 A 1 1234567890 2
564867 A 1 1234567890 2
356758 A 99 1234567890 2

Comment: The rec_cnt is not the total number of records, but the total number of unique IDSRCRECNOs for a particular IDNUMBER.  Since you only want to see records with the same IDNUMBER but different IDSRCRECNOs, I use this to filter (rec_cnt > 1).  Hindsight says this is a poorly named column, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this without a sort, using a query that would likely use a hash semijoin for large data quantities:

```
select *
from   my_table t1
where  recstat = 'A' and
       exists (
         select null
         from   my_table t2
         where  t2.IDNUMBER =  t1.IDNUMBER and
                t2.MEMRECNO != t1.MEMRECNO and
                t2.RECSTAT  =  'A')
```

Comment: Thanks David. Wouldn't this show single records as well, presuming the idnumber and memrecno match? The IDNUMBER should be linked to at least two active MEMRECNO's from different sources (IDSRCRECNO). Also, the MEMRECNO can be the same for different sources ID's, for example MEMRECNO 123456 can have two records for IDSRCRECNO 2 and IDSRCRECNO 3. Appreciate the help!

Comment: The correlation for the subquery is "not equals" for the memrecno, so it ought to be ok. For a simple and fast check on "don't correlate to this same record", you could use "t1.rowid != t1.rowid"

Answer (score 0):

I think your `WHERE` clause should be

```
WHERE idnumber in ( SELECT idnumber 
                    FROM ( SELECT count(*), idnumber 
                           FROM  table 
                           GROUP by idnumber 
                           HAVING count(*) >= 2
                         ) temp
                  )
```